# Was Yachiru real or just Zaraki's spirit?

Tags: bleach

In the final arc of Bleach, we see Yachiru going to a severely wounded Zaraki Kenpachi and talking to him. She couldn't physically be there, and she talks as if she were Nozarashi's manifestation. Yachiru is also reported has having a unique shikai.

[image]

Is Yachiru just a manifestation of Zaraki's Zanpakuto? Or did she really exists, and due to their bond, Nozarashi's spirit took her shape? or was Zaraki just dillusional?